# (Flip sorting) Same input, but different output in ideone and codeblocks

Tags: c, sorting, codeblocks

I was facing this problem during solving a problem in uVa.The name of the problem is "10327 - Flip Sort"

The problem statement is...

---

`Sorting in computer science is an important part. Almost every problem can be solved effeciently if
sorted data are found. There are some excellent sorting algorithm which has already acheived the lower
bound n · lg n. In this problem we will also discuss about a new sorting approach. In this approach
only one operation (Flip) is available and that is you can exchange two adjacent terms. If you think a
while, you will see that it is always possible to sort a set of numbers in this way.
A set of integers will be given. Now using the above approach we want to sort the numbers in
ascending order. You have to find out the minimum number of flips required. Such as to sort ‘1 2 3’
we need no flip operation whether to sort ‘2 3 1’ we need at least 2 flip operations.

Input

The input will start with a positive integer N (N ≤ 1000). In next few lines there will be N integers.
Input will be terminated by EOF.

Output

For each data set print ‘Minimum exchange operations : M’ where M is the minimum flip operations required to perform sorting. Use a seperate line for each case.

Sample Input

3

1 2 3

3

2 3 1

Sample Output

Minimum exchange operations : 0

Minimum exchange operations : 2

---

Which is pretty much simple.
Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int i,j,n,a[1001],temp,c;

while(scanf("%d",&n)!=EOF)
{
    c=0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    i=0;
    while(i<n)
    {
        j=0;
        while(j<n)
        {
            if(a[j]>a[j+1])
            {
                temp=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=temp;
                c++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("Minimum exchange operations : %d\n",c);
}

return 0;
}
```

for these following test cases:

5

6 2 1 5 4

8

3 5 8 2 1 9 7 0

2

0 0

12

0 1 2 5 4 1 2 0 5 0 7 9

50

21 5 6 5 8 452 12 5 96 21 21 5 6 5 8 452 12 5 96 21 21 5 6 5 8 452 12 5 96 21 21 5 6 5 8 452 12 5 96 21 21 5 6 5 8 452 12 5 96 21

the accepted output is

Minimum exchange operations : 6

Minimum exchange operations : 16

Minimum exchange operations : 0

Minimum exchange operations : 19

Minimum exchange operations : 485

---

Which i got in codeblocks. But ideone keeps showing these outputs ->

Minimum exchange operations : 11

Minimum exchange operations : 23

Minimum exchange operations : 0

Minimum exchange operations : 28

Minimum exchange operations : 535

---

And i keep getting wrong answer, which i have no clue why.

Comment: Your code has *undefined behaviour* because it can read and write beyond the array bounds (or use an uninitialised array element)  with `a[j+1]` when `j == n - 1`.

Comment: BTW the "flip" algorithm is not "a new sorting approach". It is a [bubble sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/) and is not very efficient.

Comment: The Geeks link I posted shows some example code. Have a close look at its iteration limits.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for your valuable comment. It helped me fix my code.